# understanding swift 3 syntax

Tags: swift, swift3

Many times encountering Swift functions compiler suggest me to write something like:

```
var personArr3 = (0...5).map(transform: (Int) throws -> (Int) throws -> >)
```

When i tap "Enter" it will evaluate to following:

```
var personArr3 = (0...5).map { (<Int>) -> T in
    <code>
}
```

And i acutally dont know what does it means.

I could write it correctly using following:

```
var personsArr2 = (0...5).map{ _ in
    Person(firstName: "Bobby", lastName: "Little")
}
```

Which is quite simpler, and provide only curly bracers.

So, my question is, how to rewrite

```
var personsArr2 = (0...5).map{ _ in
        Person(firstName: "Bobby", lastName: "Little")
    }
```

And how to understand initial suggested code? Thanks.

Comment: `personArr3` is a horrible name FYI. What's the "3" about? You should pick names like `people` over `arrayOfPerson`, `personArray`, etc.

Comment: @Alexander im just testing syntax in playground, is that really matter?

Comment: Of course. Build good habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion you provided is incorrect. What it should have shown (and probably did) was:

```
personArr3.(0...5).map(transform: (Int) throws -> T)
```

Meaning that the transformation function that `map` excepts takes a single `Int` parameter, and returns a `T`. This `T` determines the result of the result of `map`, which will be `[T]` (a.k.a. `Array<T>`).

Optionally, this transformation function can `throw` an error. If it does, then the `map` function will `rethrow` it, and it'll bubble up to where you can handle it

Comment: can you rewrite var personsArr2 = (0...5).map{ _ in
        Person(firstName: "Bobby", lastName: "Little")
    } with syntax you provided please? And explain steps and meaning of "T in", what is T?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban That function is just right. It takes an Int parameters (which is ignores, with the `_`), and returns a `T`, which works out to be `Person` in this case. As a result, the whole `map` operation returns `[Person]`.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban  `T` is a generic type, it's a place holder that let's you express relationships between the types of various features of a function or type. In this case, `T` is a generic type which expresses a relationship between the return type of transform function and the return type of the whole `map` expression. In the case of map, `T` is used to express this relationship: "Given a transformation function that takes an `Int` and returns some type, call it `T`, `map` will return an `Array` of that type, `T`."

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Check out the Swift language guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: what is purpose of Int in this function?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Well it's a `map` operation. You're mapping each element of the input sequence, in this case, `Int` elements of a `CountableClosedRange<Int>`, and *mapping* them to an array of "outputs", generated by passing each element through the `transform` function. In your case, you're ignoring these `Int`s (which makes sense, because you're just making 6 Bobby Littles, which don't need the `Int`.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban The "Closures" section of the official language guide discusses `map`, and would be of great use to you.

Comment: can you explain "T in" part? i could not compile my example. Thank you for your other explanation by the way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149414/discussion-between-alexander-and-evgeniy-kleban).